# Detect .net framework installed in target machine by Installshield

Tags: installshield-2011

How to detect if .net framework is installed or not in the target machine by Installshield?
If it is already installed how to find the installed version of .net framework?
Can anyone please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Dotnet after installing own pakage in installshield?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256100/install-dotnet-after-installing-own-pakage-in-installshield)

Comment: The question Cody Gray references has the answer to the first part. But Vimal, what do you mean by find in "find the installed version"?

Answer (score 0):

```
installshield
 stallaton designer
 system search
chose: file path,specifie by registry entry
 registry root: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
 registry key: \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL 
next
 IS_SQLSERVER_SERVER
 choise Addition Option .
```

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield has a series of predefined searches.  You should be aware that multiple versions of the .NET framework can run side by side ( 1.0, 1.1, 2.0-3.5 and 4.0 )